# Creating custom Leaflet map from series of images?

Tags: leaflet, tile-layer

I am using leaflet to display a simplified pipeline network that our users can mark up with leaflet draw.  I have achieved this by using the [crs.simple example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) on the leafletjs website.

This is fine and works for the small 1900x1080px image that I've currently been provided but we're discussing much larger networks and also different degrees of detail based on the current zoom so my understanding is that I may need to convert this into tiles.

I have seen this example using [tileLayer](http://jsfiddle.net/davido/r2ms3dnp/) which seems to achieve half of what is required but I don't know what tools are required to build the Tiles.  Also the zoomed *out* view contains the same level of detail as the zoomed *in* view so I am wondering if its possible to achieve LOD using this technique such that when zooming it it seamlessly transitions into a higher detailed pipeline network view.

Comment: You probably will need to configure a [WMTS](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wmts).

Answer (score 1):

Use GDAL2TILES to create a folder of tiles or gdal_translate to create an MBTILES or gpkg